# Android onTap Intent Array

Tags: java, android, arraylist, maps, itemizedoverlay

On my MapActivity, when you tap on an ItemizedOverlay, it displays the
Title
Snippet / Messsage in a TextView and changes each time another ItemizedOverlay is clicked or tapped

I have created an ImageButton with a phone image on it and i am trying to call an Array Intent to it 
So basically, when Users Tap on Overlay1, and then decide to tap on the Phone Image Button the number stored in the intent, changes to Overlay1's number and so they can call Overlay 1
and if they tap on Overlay 2, then the number would change accordingly etc

my Code is as follows:

```
List<Overlay> mapOverlays;
List<Intent> mapIntents;
NewItemizedOverlay itemizedOverlay;
Intent intentCall;

GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint((int)(51.555890943494276*1E6), (int)(-0.39989858865737915*1E6));
    OverlayItem overlayitem = new OverlayItem(point, "Greenwood Veterinary" , "57 Station Approach, South Ruislip, Ruislip, Middlesex, HA4 6SL, 020 8845 8144");
    itemizedOverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem);
    Intent vet1 = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_DIAL,Uri.parse("tel:020 8845 8144")); // i created this in a similar fashion to the itemizedOverlay
    intentCall.?(vet1); // i wanted to try and do the same thing with the addOverlay but i cant seem to find the correct method of doing this

GeoPoint point2 = new GeoPoint((int)(51.598707*1E6), (int)(-0.393416*1E6));
    OverlayItem overlayitem2 = new OverlayItem(point2, "MediVet Pinner" , "2A Pinner Green, Pinner, Middlesex, HA5 2AA, 020 8866 0727");
    itemizedOverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem2);
    Intent vet2 = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_DIAL,Uri.parse("tel:020 8866 0727"));
```

ItemizedOverlay:

```
private ArrayList<OverlayItem> mOverlays = new ArrayList<OverlayItem>();
private ArrayList<Intent> cIntents = new ArrayList<Intent>();
Context mContext;

   public NewItemizedOverlay(Drawable defaultMarker) {
           super(boundCenterBottom(defaultMarker));
   }

   public NewItemizedOverlay(Drawable defaultMarker, Context context)
   {
           super(boundCenterBottom(defaultMarker));
           mContext = context;
   }

   public void addOverlay(OverlayItem overlay)
   {
           mOverlays.add(overlay);
           populate();
   }

   public void addOverlay(OverlayItem overlay, Intent intent)
   {
           mOverlays.add(overlay);
           cIntents.add(intent);
           populate();
   }

   @Override
   protected OverlayItem createItem(int i) {
           // TODO Auto-generated method stub
           return mOverlays.get(i);
   }

   protected Intent createCall(int c)
   {
           return cIntents.get(c);
   }

   @Override
   public int size() {
           // TODO Auto-generated method stub
           return mOverlays.size();
   }

   public int callsize()
   {
           return cIntents.size();
   }

   @Override
   protected boolean onTap(int index) {
     OverlayItem item = mOverlays.get(index);
     Intent callItem = cIntents.get(index);


     AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
     dialog.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_info);
     dialog.setTitle(item.getTitle());
     dialog.setMessage(item.getSnippet());
     dialog.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

           @Override
           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                   // TODO Auto-generated method stub

           }
   });
     dialog.setNeutralButton("Call", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                   @Override
                   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                           // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                           VetNumber. //Not sure how to exactly call the Intent
                   }
           });
     dialog.show();
     return true;
   }

}
```

If anyone could help, i would be very grateful

Thank You

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's too late for you, but you can start a new intent if you know the context where you are. If you're working with MapActivity and ItemizedOverlay you can get the context in LocalizacionItemizedOverlay.

```
Context mContext;
public LocalizacionItemizedOverlay(Drawable defaultMarker, Context context) {
    super(boundCenterBottom(defaultMarker));
    mContext=context;
}
```

Then in the onTap function you can write some similar to:

```
dialog.setPositiveButton("Ver", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
      Intent nextScreen = new Intent(mContext, YourActivity.class); //define the intent
  nextScreen.putExtra("definicionURL",definicion.url); //pass variables
  mContext.startActivity(nextScreen); //launch the intent
   }
});
```

This has been my first post in stackoverflow.com and I want to say something to all people posting solutions here: thank you very much.